# Windows no reconoce comando touch

Tags: windows, terminal, vscode

Trato de ejecutar el comando: "touch .gitignore" pero me da este error
[image: Imagen con el Error]

Comment: Esto es windows no? y visual studio code?

Comment: si, si, lo siento se me olvidó agregarlo a la descripción

Comment: Si estás usando Nodejs puedes usar este comando para instalarlo: ``npm install touch-cli -g``

Answer (score 4):

> Esta respuesta esta copiada de
>   [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37756874/73749)

En la ventana de comandos podes hacer

```
type nul > tuarchivo.txt
```

Esto va a crear un archivo de 0 bytes con el nombre tuarchivo.txt

Otra forma de hacerlo es usando el comando echo

```
echo.>tuarchivo.txt
```

echo. - va a crear el archivo con solo una fila vacia dentro de el.

Comment: Use el mismo comando para crear directorios type nul > file.extension ejemplo: type nul > index.html no funciona para power shell sólo cmd

Answer (score 0):

No existe un comando `touch` incluido por defecto en Windows. Tu puedes usar algún comando equivalente o instalar alguna versión para windows.

- Puedes instalar una versión de [touch para Windows](http://www.binarez.com/touch_dot_exe/)
- Si quieres usar otros comandos utilizados en Linux, puedes instalar las utilidades de [GNU Win32 coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) o las utilidades de [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) usadas en MinGW. Estas son las versiones de Linux compiladas de nuevo en Windows.

**NOTA:** Si quieres contar con una versión completa de Linux en tu máquina, puedes usar el [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). Puedes ejecutar [comandos Linux desde la línea de comandos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop).

Answer (score 0):

También puedes crear un nuevo archivo utilizando el Windows Power Shell con el comando `ni .gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

si estás en Vs code puedes usar el comando "code", para indicarle a Vs code que quieres abrir un archivo de ese nombre. al no existir uno lo creara para ti y lo abrirá.

```
code nombre_de_archivo.extension
```

también puedes incluir la ruta completa del archivo.

```
code carpeta-raiz/sub-carpeta/archivo.extension
```

Answer (score -2):

En `windows` puedes utilizar este comando que funcionó para mi:

```
fsutil file createnew filename 0
```

En tu caso:

`fsutil file createnew .gitignore 0`